# Express.js: How to use Template Literals in JSON?

Tags: json, express, postman, wysiwyg, literals

I have this JSON object in a file called db.json:

```
"lyrics": "Am9 Keep you in the dark F#m7(b5)  F7M You know they all pretend Am9 Keep you in the dark F#m7(b5)  F7M And so it all began"
```

and this code in a js file:

```
exports.addLyrics = (req, res, next) => {
    const lyric = req.body;
    db.get('lyrics').push(lyric).last().assign({
        id: Date.now().toString()
    }).write();

    res.status(200).send(lyric);
};
```

I am using postman and would like to post lyrics with template literals so I could pass the lyric chords on the right positions, something like this:

```
"lyrics": `
 Am9
Keep you in the dark
              F#m7(b5)  F7M
You know they all   pretend
 Am9
Keep you in the dark

          F#m7(b5)  F7M
And so it all    began`
```

**Question:** How to store and load Template Literals as JSON in this situation?

Comment: You cannot load literals from an external file. That's the point of a literal - it sits *in your source code* and creates a literal value when the source code is parsed. Nothing you load from a text file can do that.

Comment: That being said, JSON can contain the string in the format you want. Why do you have it all on one line to begin with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tomalak, I would like to see a code of someone actually solving this. You are right about the one line thing, I wouldn't do it, I actually just added to illustrate the issue, maybe it was unnecessary.

Comment: Again: Why does the JSON file not already contain the data in the right format? How is that JSON file being created? What is `db.get()` anyway? That's not standard JS, so it's some kind of module you did not disclose. There are still way too many things unclear about your question at this point.